# verify if each function started with a comment and verify if this comments contains reserved words.comments contains reserved words

Tags: javacc

I checked if each function `Function()` started with a comments in input file stream. this like :

```
     SKIP : {   " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }

            /* COMMENTS */ 

SPECIAL_TOKEN : {   <SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT: "--" (~["\n","\r"])* ("\n"|"\r"|"\r\n")?> } 


     void  Function : {
                Token firstToken, id;} {
                firstToken=<start> id=<id> "("  ")"
                .........

                <end>
                { if( firstToken.specialToken == null
                   || firstToken.specialToken.kind != COMMENT ) 
                       System.out.println("Function " +id.image+
                                          " is not preceded by a comment!" ) ;
                } }
```

so, I want to verify if this comments contains reserved words.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest using Java's regular expressions to search for keywords in `firstToken.specialToken.image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to know if a comment contains given word, you might as well use Java's string search mechanism. Suppose you want to know whether the word "bandersnatch" in the comment that precedes the function definition.

```
   void  Function() : {
        Token firstToken, id;}
   {
        firstToken=<start> id=<id> "("  ")"
        .........
        <end>
        { if( firstToken.specialToken == null
           || firstToken.specialToken.kind != COMMENT ) 
               System.out.println("Function " +id.image+
                                  " is not preceded by a comment!" ) ;
          else {
              String comment = firstToken.specialToken.image ;
              boolean hasBandersnatch = comment.indexOf("bandersnatch") != -1 ;                   if( ! hasBandersnatch ) 
                  System.out.println("Function " +id.image+
                                  " is preceded by a comment that does not contain 'bandersnatch'!" ) ; }
        }
   }
```

If you wan the search to be case insensitive change the initialization of `comment`.

```
String comment = firstToken.specialToken.image.toLower() ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it 'is work fine. but  to be case insensitive, I have change the initialization of comment like : `String comment = firstToken.specialToken.image.toLower()` and   `boolean hasBandersnatch = comment.indexOf("bandersnatch".toLower())`. Thank you